# Adjust barchart y-axis so that vastly higher y-values can be plotted nicely

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart, yaxis

I am creating a barplot with some values by using R and ggplot2. Creating the plot and everything works nicely, however, I have y-values that are mainly in one general value range with one or two vastly higher values mixed in.

To clarify, my y-values look similar to this:

[10, 12, 13, 5000, 14, 11]

```
y = c(10, 12, 13, 5000, 14, 11)
```

(For the sake of completeness: the x-values are simple increments of time, e.g. 1,2,3,4,5)

Creating the plot and everything works nicely, except that due the vastly higher value, the whole chart is very "zoomed out". I know I can filter out these higher values by setting limits, however I would like to keep them in the plot and hence wonder if there is any way to set a visible "break" in the y-scale so that it proceeds at a value that is in the range of the higher value.

I have a created a little picture using paint to clarify what I mean:

[image]

Is there any way to do this using R/ggplots2? Alternatively, I'd also like to know if anybody has any alternative ideas of how these kind of values can be nicely plotted without having to note them separately.

Thanks,

Klinring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by creating a new binary variable depending on the value of `y`. In order to do that, a threshold must be established beforehand.

```
library(ggplot2)

threshold <- 25
df1$big <- factor(df1$y <= threshold, labels = c("> 25", "<= 25"))

ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ big, "free_y", nrow = 2)
```

[image]

Then the new variable can be removed.

```
df1$big <- NULL
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:6], 
                  y = c(10, 12, 13, 5000, 14, 11))
```